# Swift 3 Error UILabel: the use of CGColor for color properties or inside attributed strings is not supported

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsattributedstring

My app is crashing when trying to create an `NSAttributedString`. I'm getting the error:

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UILabel: the use of CGColor for color properties or inside attributed strings is not supported.'

This did not happen before upgrading to Swift 3, Xcode 8

This is my code:

```
let encodedData = someHtmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!

let attributedOptions: [String:Any] = [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                        NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue]

do {
    let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
}
```

I can't understand what `CGColor` has to do with this.

**Edit**: I'm using the attributedString like so:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = attributedString.string
```

But this code is not executed. The app crashes in the 'try' scope.

The string I'm passing in (`someHtmlString`) has:

```
<ul>  <li>Up to 2 children 11 years old and younger stay free when occupying the parent or guardian\'s room, using existing bedding. </li><li>Only registered guests are allowed in the guestrooms. </li> <li>The property has connecting/adjoining rooms, which are subject to availability and can be requested by contacting the property using the number on the booking confirmation. </li><li>Some facilities may have restricted access. Guests can contact the property for details using the contact information on the booking confirmation. </li> </ul>
```

**Edit 2** 
Something weird is happening. I commented out the call to this code, and the app still crashes with the same error. So the "All exceptions" breakpoint was pointing me to the wrong place.

**Edit 3** See my solution below

Comment: What is the string you  are setting on your label?

Comment: I think it should work fine. Show the string you are setting. Whats there in your `someHtmlString` variable. Also tell your line of crash

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked, used let someHtmlString = "sdcsdsd".
Looks like your string causes the problem here. Could you share it?

Comment: @Shaked Sayag can you add the `html` that causes the error to your question? This would help.

Comment: I just added it. Thanks

Comment: It works for me with your string also. Is your function marked as throwing? If it's not, you should add *catch* block after *do* block.

Comment: @Shaked Sayag I also tried your code in a playground and there is no error.

Comment: There is a catch block, which is not reached. Do I need to write throwing in the function declaration?

Comment: @ShakedSayag Check the edit

Comment: @ShakedSayag Does your code also crash when executed in a playground? If not - maybe a `Product/Clean` helps.

Comment: In playground it works fine. Clean did not help. Thanks

Comment: Maybe app crashes on different thread or does not crash at all. Try to disable *All exceptions breakpoints* and try again.

Comment: @Povilas, Thanks. The exception did in fact occur else where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some commenting out, I found the problem was in this code:

```
let mutableAttributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString
let textColor = label.textColor
let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttributedStr.length)
mutableAttributedStr.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor], range: textRange)
```

`textColor` was resulting in an Optional type (with a value, not nil).
Once I added a `!` to the following line, it worked. Not sure why this suddenly became an issue in Swift 3/iOS 10.

```
let textColor = label.textColor!
```

Answer (score 3):

Snap! as I just had a typo, was adding `UIFont` on a color attribute, as such:

```
[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIFont]
```

Comment: In my case was something similar, I was assigning to .foregroundColor the hexString of the color instead of UIColor(hexString: "")

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

Check [Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bpxdqxycdtavd62/AAB_8hHwdrOrlwk76zzuvjqha?dl=0)

Use

```
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

And my output by your very own code by just using my above line in place of your `label.text = attributedString.string`. Just keep lines to 0 for label and provide a lead and trail constraint.

My code

```
let someHtmlString = "<ul>  <li>Up to 2 children 11 years old and younger stay free when occupying the parent or guardian\'s room, using existing bedding. </li><li>Only registered guests are allowed in the guestrooms. </li> <li>The property has connecting/adjoining rooms, which are subject to availability and can be requested by contacting the property using the number on the booking confirmation. </li><li>Some facilities may have restricted access. Guests can contact the property for details using the contact information on the booking confirmation. </li> </ul>"

let encodedData = someHtmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!

let attributedOptions: [String:Any] = [
    NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue            
]

do {
    let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
    myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
    //or use myLabel.text = attributedString.string
} catch {
}
```

[image]

Comment: any reason for downvote? I don't find anything wrong here.If someone downvotes, kindly provide the reason too.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think you're downvoted because you're not answering the question. Code crashes before setting the text.

Comment: Man, @Povilas did you see the edit. He told that he is using the label and setting the string as a text by using the string property which just removes all attributes from an attributed string

Comment: @Rajan Maheshwari using `attributedText`  has nothing to do with the question. There are reasons to use the `string` property of an `AttributedString` - like having the html-tags removed.

Comment: @d.felber when you use a string, you just remove the attributes, it will become a simple plain text and not a attributed string. Check the edit with my piece of code

Comment: @Rajan Maheshwari Nope. Line breaks and basic formatting still remains. If he wants to use the string property - you should let him ;)

Comment: I tried this, this doesn't solve the problem. The code that sets the string to the label is not executed.

Comment: Where is your label and where is your line written when you set the string to label. Check the edit

Comment: Again, the code after the try is not executed because the app crashes at that point.

Comment: BTW i have attached a sample link where you can download my test project. You are still not informing about where exactly your code crash.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari: Thanks for your help! I found it crashes elsewhere, see my answer.